# Ollydbg watch/conditional breakpoint expression for Flag registers?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

So I have been reversing a piece of malware recently and figured I could use a conditional breakpoint that would break whenever the zero flag was set for a specific jz command. I read the documentation on the web and in the help file that olly provides but can't find any examples of how I would do that. In the online documentation it says that the EFL or Flags registers can be used in a watch/conditional breakpoint expression but no mention on how to refer to them. I tried a simple expression such as ZF == 1 as well as ZF = 1 (just in case i had it wrong) and it didnt work. I searched google like mad and nothing so I am hoping someone out there has found some way to reference the flags register. For those of you who wonder why I don't just use an expression without the flags register well, I am more curious as to how to reference the flags register in the event I really need it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't break on a particular flag name for EFLAGS, but you can get the value from EFLAGS, so you still have multiple possibilities from there:

note: tested on Ollydbg v2.01

1) Break on the whole value of EFLAGS (note that the value of EFLAGS register for ollydbg conditionnal syntax is either `EFL` or `FLAGS`).

```
EFL==0x246
```

2) break on a particular flag

- You need to know the [flag position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register#Flags), e.g. ZF is bit 6 (start counting from 0).
- Either use the bit position as a mask:

  example with ZF (bit 6 set to 1 is 0x40): `(EFL & 0x40)==0x40`
- Shift the flags by its position, mask it only and test for it:

  example with ZF (bit 6): `(EFL >> 6) & 1==1`

Comment: So it looks like versions 1.10 to 2.0 do not allow for the referencing of the EFL nor the FLAGS register. It seems to only of been added to version 2.01. After some testing I noticed that my watches using both the EFL and FLAGS register were indeed showing the values as I wanted. As soon as I tried to create conditional breakpoints I ran into the issue that they were not being hit despite the face that the EFL register was exactly the condition I had set.

Comment: I noticed that to trigger this conditional breakpoint I had to add a normal int3 breakpoint before the conditional to get it to trigger. Would you happen to know why I would have to add the breakpoint before the conditional by any chance? I didn't see mention of it anywhere and I find it weird that it is necessary to have the conditional breakpoint working. Thank you very much for sharing the fact that it works on 2.01 since I was using only v1.10 and v2.0.

Comment: @John I tested it once again (still on v2.01) and couldn't reproduce your problem: my conditional BP is hit **without** any "regular" BP before it on my test program (tried it on Windows 10 *calc.exe*; put multiple cond. BP on some JZ and JNZ jcc and run the program right from the entry point).